# include not working for some reason

Tags: php

In my php code there is a section which needs to be retrieved from another php file. 
I tried accomplishing this by:

```
include "teams.php?id=".$matchid;
```

and in the teams.php

```
$matchid = $_GET['id'];
echo "MATCH ID IS ".$matchid;
```

The problem is when i open teams.php?id=".$matchid directly it displays the match id fine

however the include doesn't work - i checked the source code of the original page - no code is being inserted. Is there a way to do what i want? I need to get php code from another file whilst passing 2 variables onto that file

Comment: Is the code you need in teams.php or does teams.php load another file depending on the matchid?

Comment: the code i need is in teams.php but the variables in teams.php will depend in matchid since teams.php recieve the matchid and does a search in the database for the match and sends back the data to the main page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

The problem is related to [what `$_GET` really contains](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php):

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters. (...)

And you do not pass `$matchid` to the script through URL... And you should not in this case.

### Solution

But there is a way. PHP does not separate global variables among files, so variables available in one file are available also in the one included:

- in file no. 1:

  ```php
  // Assume $matchid is defined
  include "teams.php";
  ```
- in file no. 2 (the one included):

  ```php
  // No need to redefine $matchid - it was defined in the first file
  echo "MATCH ID IS ".$matchid;
  ```

Also make sure you add `<?php` at the beginning of the file (the closing tag is not required). Otherwise it will be treated as text and not executed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aren't loading that page in the browser when you call the include function, so the variable you are appending is not being processed as a URL query param. You are really just taking everything inside teams.php and dumping it into the other file (the one including teams.php) at that position.

If you want to effectively pass something into teams.php then just declare a variable before the include.

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php and all will become clear.

Comment: oh my how stupid am i. of course it doesn't treat the include as a separate page so i can carry on working with the original variables. Thank you this simplifies things so much!

Answer (score 0):

That's not how include's work.  When you include a file, it's code is executed as if it was written in the same file it's being included in.  So teams.php will have the variable $matchid when the including file has that variable, no need to pass it in.  Also the way you called the include was incorrect.  Doing what you did causes php to look for a file in the current directory called 'teams.php?id=0' (replace 0 with the $matchid value).  This file does not exist, 'teams.php' exists, not the URI.  It is possible to specify a url by prefixing it with 'http://' however the result would work with the code in teams.php as it would expect to be able to read the php source.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this `include "include "teams.php?id={$matchid}";` and
`$matchid = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
echo "MATCH ID IS {$matchid}";`

If You will use this code, you will be safe from Injects too!
I hope you will apreciate this.